# IndexError при работе с sqlite3 объектом cursor

Tags: python-3.x, база-данных, разработка-игр, sqlite3

Недавно начал работать с sqlite, была готовая игра тетрис, решил к ней сделать таблицу показывающую топ победителей сначала я запрашиваю имя игрока, а в конце игры добавляю данные в базу(проверяю уже существующие данные если они меньше новые то добавляю новые). Но когда пытаюсь считать то что вывел SELECT вылазит ошибка list index out of range
'''

```
import sqlite3 as sq


def player(username):
    with sq.connect('tetris.db') as con:

        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player(
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
        best_time INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        best_score INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
        games INTEGER DEFAULT 0
        )''')
        x = list(cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM player WHERE name = ?''', (username,)))
        if len(x) == 0:
            cur.execute('''INSERT INTO player(name) VALUES(?)''', (username,))


def end_game(point, time, username):
    with sq.connect('tetris.db') as con:
        data = (point, time, username)
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT best_time, best_score FROM player WHERE name == ?', (username,))
        print([[j for j in i] for i in cur.fetchmany(1)])
        old_time, old_point = [[j for j in i] for i in cur.fetchmany(1)]
        if old_time >= time:
            time = old_time
        if old_point >= point:
            point = old_point
        cur.execute('UPDATE player SET best_time = ?1, best_score = ?2, games = games + 1 where name = ?3', data)
```

'''

Comment: Запомните куда-нибудь результат фетча: `rows = cur.fetchone()` и работайте дальше с переменной. Сейчас вы когда второй раз вызываете `cur.fetchmany(1)`, то читать уже нечего - всё прочиталось когда вы `print` делали.

Comment: Но вообще нужно показывать полный стек-трейс ошибки в вопросе. Ошибка может возникнуть в нескольких местах программы, без привязки к конкретному месту кода (написанному в стек-трейсе) диагностировать проблему сложнее.